# Muliprocessing module not functioning as expected: not outputing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I ran the following code but it didn't output anything. I even included the argument `[i]` but nothing.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
The expected output is:

    worker,
    worker,
    worker,
    worker,
    worker
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it, it works as expected. It may be because script will run too fast. Before the process get the chance to write to stdout, program reaches the end therefor you can't see the results.

Wait for jobs to finish.

```
for i in jobs: i.join()
```

Comment: its just running endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. The items have to be `put in a q`  and then you `get` them from the `q` one after the other. See solution below, there may be a better solutions, but this works perfectly.

```
from  multiprocessing import Process, Queue
def worker(q):
    """worker function"""
    q.put('Worker')

q=Queue()    
jobs=[]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        print q.get()
        p.join()
```

I hope to find other solutions.